# Non base-level NSUserDefaults keys inaccessible to Bundle.settings?

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I store my app's settings in an NSDictionary which I then write to NSUserDefaults, like so:

```
NSUserDefaults*  defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:settingsDictionary forKey:@"myAppSettings"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

I wanted the settings to be editable in the Settings.app, so I made a Settings.bundle and set about mapping the controls to my keys. But it looks like key paths don't work as the Settings.app inserts unwelcome keys like "myAppSettings.aSetting" into the base level of my defaults.

Does Settings.bundle really require you to store all your settings in the base level?